# Connection to 172.0.0.1 from an App on an Android Device fails with Timeout

Tags: android, http, timeout, localhost

i want to develop a app that enables two Android phones to exchange data over the Wifi Network. Since im not having two phones at the moment i thought i can try this by using 1 App that acts as a Server and another App that connects to 172.0.0.1 as a Client.
In the Server-App i start a Service that runs a NanoHTTPD Server. As a test i want to Recieve "Hallo Client" when i ask for `http://172.0.0.1:8080/hallo/` . This works with the normal Android Browser.

This is what the Server looks like:

```
@Override
public Response serve(String uri, String method, Properties header, Properties parms, Properties files)
    {
        Log.d("HServer", "httpd request >>" + method + " '" + uri + "' " + "   " + parms);

        if (uri.startsWith("/hallo/"))
        {
            return new Response(HTTP_OK, MIME_PLAINTEXT, "Hallo Client");
        }
        else
        {
            return new Response(HTTP_OK, MIME_PLAINTEXT, "");
        }
    }
```

Then i made a second App with a simple test with an HttpURLConnection after the Google Example:

```
private String NetworkResponse;
    private Runnable Erg = new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TV1.setText(NetworkResponse);
            Log.d("bla", NetworkResponse);
        }
    };

    public void Request(View view)
    {

        mHandler = new Handler();
        Thread T = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {


                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                try
                {
                    URL url = new URL("http://172.0.0.1:8080/hallo/");
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    NetworkResponse = readIt(in,1000);
                    mHandler.post(Erg);
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }

            }
        });
        T.start();
    }

    private String readIt(BufferedInputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }
}
```

This Code works when the URL is something like `http://en.wikipedia.org` but not with `http://172.0.0.1:8080/hallo/` . I get

```
07-12 01:20:00.398: W/System.err(17234): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /172.0.0.1 (port 8080) after 10000ms.
```

So my question is: why does the Android Browser recieve an answer from my simple Server and my own App does not? Is something wrong with the way im using the HttpURLConnection?
(P.S: Im not using the Emulator, everyting is on a real Phone, both Apps have all the Permissions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try 127.0.0.1 instead of 172.0.0.1.

Comment: omg it worked.Sorry for the stupid Question. Sometimes i´m not able to see the obvious mistake

Comment: Glad it worked.  Sometimes the "obvious" mistakes are the hardest to see.  Please click and accept this answer if it helped.